# PHP - Quote characters

Tags: php, character-encoding, special-characters

When I post something to my database that have ' or é etc. I get this:

```
Don&amp;#039;t worry guys,
```

Which should be:

```
Don't worry guys
```

This is how I add text to the database:

```
$text = $_POST['text'];
            $text = mb_convert_encoding($text, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');
            $text = htmlentities($text, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
```

And here is some information about my table in the database:

```
Format  dynamic
Character Set (Sorting) utf8_general_ci
```

Comment: Well yeah, that's what `htmlentities()` does. What are you expecting?

Comment: so what your question exactly is?

Comment: First of all you seem to be converting the input string from UTF-8 to UTF-8 which is redundant. I'm not sure if this is some hackish workaround to deal with PHP multi-byte strings, if so then ignore my remark. The problem is caused by your call of htmlentities, which converts your special characters into HTML entities. Store in the database the raw original UTF-8 string. Only if you want to embed it in your HTML output, you must make sure to convert HTML control characters into entities, in order to avoid code injection.

Comment: I'd advocate saving as raw text in your database and converting to HTML only when rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although this is not a good practice to avoid sql injection
use `html_entity_decode()` to decode html entites to solve that problem

Answer (score 1):

Use `htmlspecialchars()` instead of `htmlentities()` to get the result you want in this case:

```
htmlspecialchars($text, ENT_COMPAT | ENT_HTML401, 'UTF-8')
```